# jQuery run function in context of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have some function that (for example only) looks for all divs and appends to them.

```
function test() {
    $('div').append(/*...*/);
}
```

Now I'm loading new divs via $.get function to my container element.
After loading of new divs I want to call test() function in contex (limited to) my container element. I only want to append sth to new divs. I dan't want to append twice to old divs.

I don't want to edit test function if it is possible.

Comment: do you have some parent div for new divs?

Comment: `$('div')` selects all `<div>` elements. You'd have to modify your selector to `$(parent, 'div')` and provide a `parent` argument to `test`.

Comment: you will have to edit test function if it's selector is `'div'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function test(container) {
    $(container).find('div').append(/*...*/);
}
```

used like:

```
test("body");
test("#mainContainer");
test("ul.spiffy > li");
```

In short, you simply pass in the selector that you want to modify divs inside.

If you want to allow for a "default" value, you can do something like this:

```
function test(container) {
    if (container == undefined) container = "body";
    $(container).find('div').append(/*...*/);
}
```

Now, if you pass no parameter to test, it will apply the `append` to all `div` elements inside of `body`.

Comment: Is there really no way to limit it without modifying that function?

Comment: @Hooch Correct. But doing it this way will provide flexibility.

Comment: @Hooch tough luck? Without modifying that function, you can't change how it behaves.

Comment: How can I add default argument? I mean. If I pass nothing I want it to apply to whole document. Then I'll accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div', 'container').append(/* code */);
```